# Is that a good practice to provide a aggregation API in a Rest or a normal WebAPI Design?

Tags: rest, api-design, url-design

I have provide such REST API for getting base user info and user's space info.

**/v1/users/{user_id}/profile**, which will return such a JSON:

```json
{

"id":123,
  "name":"foo",
  "sex":0,
  "email":"foo@gmail.com",
}
```

**/v1/users/{user_id}/space** , which also return a JSON:

```json
{
  "sum_space":100,
  "used_space":20,
}

Now if a client (e.g. web page, a 3rd application) have a view which need to show part of user info(e.g "name", "sex") and part of user space info (e.g "sum_space") in a same time, Do I need to provide a new aggregation API such like `/v1/users/{user_id}`?

And if I provide such a aggregation API, should it return all attributes of User and Space? if I did so, the return value will include some unused values, which will increase the bandwidth of network. But if this API just return what client need, what should I do if a new client requirement come(e.g just get a user's name and user's used_space)?

If I don't provide any aggregation API, all the client must call N times for getting N kinds of resource. if there are a requirement for filter search(e.g getting user list which sum space > 100), the client could only do this serially.

I am very confuse about those, is that any guideline to follow?

Answer (score 1):

Provide base data at `/users/{id}`. Allow clients to include the optional query parameter `?expand=profile, space`. If they pick both, they get a detailed response with data from all three endpoints. If they only pick, say, `profile`, then they get the base data and the profile data.

If you need them to be able to restrict to exactly the properties they need, you can also support an `?include` query parameter, that might look like `GET /users/{id}?include=id,lastModifiedDate,profile.name&expand=profile` and might get back something like

```
{
    "id": 25,
    "lastModifiedDate": 0,
    "profile": {
        "name": "Bob Smith"
    }
}
```

You can mess around with the URI structure above as you like. Maybe you prefer `GET /users/{id}?include=id,lastModifiedDate&expand=profile[name]`. The point is that you can use query parameters to define the type of information you get back.

Another choice, if you're using vendor-specific MIME types, would be to use a different mime type for different shapes of response. One type might return the profile and space, while another would return just one or the other, when a request is made to `GET /users/{id}`. That's a particularly blunt instrument though, and it doesn't sound appropriate for your needs.